# Animating a custom CAShapeLayer at a variable rate

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, cashapelayer, cabasicanimation

I have a series of arcs, all created with code like this and animated with CABasicAnimation @"strokeEnd".

```
        if (!_fourthShapeLayer) {
            _fourthPath =  [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(rect.size.width / 2, rect.size.height / 2)
                                                         radius:rect.size.width / 2 - 9.5
                                                     startAngle:startAngle
                                                       endAngle:startAngle - (endAngle - startAngle)
                                                      clockwise:YES];
            _fourthShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
            _fourthShapeLayer.path = _fourthPath.CGPath;
            _fourthShapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
            _fourthShapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:.33888889 saturation:.62 brightness:0.62 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
            _fourthShapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
            _fourthShapeLayer.rasterizationScale = 2.0 * [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
            _fourthShapeLayer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        }

        CABasicAnimation *strokeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
        strokeAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
        strokeAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
        strokeAnimation.duration = 1.0;
        strokeAnimation.speed = 1.0;
        [_fourthShapeLayer addAnimation:strokeAnimation forKey:@"stroke"];

        [self.layer addSublayer:_fourthShapeLayer];
```

What varies is the color, and the radius when defining the path.

I would like to alter the rate of the arcs' animations to do the following: all start and end at the same time, yet have varying rates. Basically, some arcs start fast and end slow, the others start slow and end fast - all at different rates.

It would be great if I could define the amount of arc drawn like this: pow((elapsedAnimationTime / totalAnimationTime), 1.05) - varying the 'power' (1.05, 1.02, .97, .91 for the different arcs, for instance).

Does anyone have any suggestions? Originally I set a timer and called drawRect: every hundredth of a second, defining the path end points according to the 'power' function mentioned above - but of course this was too costly an operation.

Help appreciated!

Comment: By the way, if you do the timer-based approach in the future (for some animations, it is the best way to do it), it's better to use `CADisplayLink`, which is automatically coordinated with screen updates.

Comment: @Rob Awesome suggestion. Big Thanks.

Comment: While using CABasicAnimation and altering the timingFunction property (Alex's answer, see below) was most efficient for the CPU, it resulted in some finicky behavior, including the arcs briefly disappearing as the animation completes. The CADisplayLink proved to be a better solution in this case for it provided optimum control without strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom `timingFunction`, e.g.:

```
animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithControlPoints:0.5:0:0.9:0.7];
```

More on this here: [Animations Explained](https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/)